# Sort even numbers, then odd numbers

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports, modulo

I need to sort street addresses for people to walk on either side of the street. Therefore I need to order the even address numbers first, then the odd numbers.

I've already managed to sort by street name, but now how do I sort the data by evens and then odds within the streets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new formula called EvenOrOdd:

```
ToNumber({addressNumber}) MOD 2
```

This returns 0 when a number is even, and 1 when a number is odd. Then add a new Group inside your existing group and sort based on EvenOrOdd.

Comment: "Then add a new Group inside your existing group and sort based on EvenOrOdd."

Not sure what this means but thank you. I am RTFM now. I am working with an existing template but I don't think it was created properly in the first place which is why I am having trouble. The output I get is almost correct, but has issues when there is an apartment number, which shouldn't even be part of the address number sorting.

Comment: If a group includes apartment number like 2043 place apt 6, is there a way to sort only by the first number and ignore the 6?

Comment: Sure, you could write a formula to crop out everything after the first Space in your Apartment Number string, then convert the resulting string `2043` to a number value. Something like `Left(AddressField, Instr(1, AddressField, " ") - 1)`

Comment: nevermind I got it sorted out. some of the numbers were being imported as strings, throwing off the sorting. we also had a convoluted way of calculating even/odd so changing that to mod 2 was super helpful thanks again